# Background color of parent tr of table not working if its child cells(td) are invisible, for chrome browser

Tags: html, css

I have a case as in this jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/n5s53v32/6/

**HTML:**

```
<table>
 <tr>
  <td>td 1</td>
  <td>td 2</td>
  <td class="last">td 3</td>
</tr>
<tr class="bg">
 <td>td 1</td>
 <td class="hide">td 2</td>
 <td class="last">td 3</td>
</tr>
<tr>
 <td>td 1</td>
 <td>td 2</td>
 <td class="last">td 3</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

**CSS:**

```
.bg{background: red; }
.hide{visibility:hidden; }
```

If child cells(td) of a tr are set invisible then background color of parent tr on invisible portion does not work in chrome browser, But its working in firefox.

Edit: JS fiddle updated http://jsfiddle.net/n5s53v32/11/

Comment: Just info: remove the `width` from `.bg` without value. But it intresting

Comment: You can use `.hide{opacity:0 }`this.

Comment: What about using `opacity`? You can also use `pointer-events:none` to mimic the effect of hiding visibility. http://jsfiddle.net/teddyrised/n5s53v32/8/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

demo - http://jsfiddle.net/n5s53v32/7/

use opacity

```
.hide {
    opacity:0;
}
```

Comment: Keep in mind that the element can still be clickable (an anchor link, for instance)

Answer (score 2):

Try like this:- 
**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/n5s53v32/9/)**

```
.hide{
    /* visibility:hidden; */
        opacity:0 
}
```

use `opacity`